# Can't export String as Hyperlink in .xlsx File - Java 8 & POI 3.17

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, apache-poi

I try to build an Excel file where the first cell is everytime a Hyperlink. I use Java 8 and POI 3.17 in a Spring Boot API. The excel export works fine, but the problem is, that the first cell is now complete empty. I don't get any warning or error or something else. The Problematic code:

```
  final XSSFWorkbook wb = exportHelperService.loadWorkbookTemplate(path);
  XSSFHyperlink url_link = wb.getCreationHelper().createHyperlink(HyperlinkType.URL) // definition for Hyperlink


  fillWorkbook(....) {  // here i gonna fill my workbook - everything works fine

    url_link.setAddress("http://www.google.de/");  // definition of url address - checked that its not empty

    exportHelperService.insertHyperlinkValue(url_link, "Cell_1", row);  // calls function that writes into the cell 1 - for all other cells there is NO problem

    // ... code that works fine ...

  }


  public void insertHyperlinkValue(XSSFHyperlink value, String columName, Row row) {
    if (value != null) {
        Cell cell = row.getCell(columnIndexMap.get(columName), CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
        cell.setHyperlink(value); // <--- HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    }
}
```

I tested the insertHyperlinkValue() function to print only a string and it worked fine, but for a hyperlink it don't wanna work... Where is my false ? Thank you very much for each answer !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cell already holds the link, it just has no text/style.

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFHyperlink link = wb.getCreationHelper().createHyperlink(HyperlinkType.URL);
XSSFCellStyle hlinkstyle = wb.createCellStyle();
XSSFFont hlinkfont = wb.createFont();
hlinkfont.setUnderline(XSSFFont.U_SINGLE);
hlinkfont.setColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.index);
hlinkstyle.setFont(hlinkfont);
link.setAddress("http://www.google.de/");
Sheet s = wb.createSheet();
Row r = s.createRow(0);
Cell c = r.createCell(0);
c.setHyperlink(link);
c.setCellStyle(hlinkstyle);  //<-- make it look like link
c.setCellValue(link.getAddress());  // <-- important
wb.write(new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\Test\\hyperlink.xlsx")));
wb.close();
```

You just need to set the cell text and style and you are good to go.

Comment: Wow ok now i understand my false ... Thank you very very much !!!! Now i can see the link without problem :). I have only 1 last question. How is it possible, to make this link clickable? It has the optics of a link yes, but i didn't found anything about to make it clicky

Comment: For me it is clickable by default. Like when I click on the cell with the link it open google

Comment: The problem that i have is that only the last entry is clickable ... if i have 10 times www.google.com, only the 10th entry can be clicked ...

Comment: Ok i fixed it. In my for loop i initialize in EVERY ITERATION the link new. So all rows gonna be clickable. Thank you very much for your answer !!!!